# Leave process hanging/running in background and write to same file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to record capacity utilization while running other (Python) processes with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm results/*

top -U $USER > results/test_utilization.txt &

# Give `top` enough time to record something
python3 -c 'import time;time.sleep(10)'

echo "JOB_1_COMPLETE" >> results/test_utilization.txt

python3 -c 'import time;time.sleep(10)'

echo "JOB_2_COMPLETE" >> results/test_utilization.txt

kill %1
```

My hope is that running something like `echo "JOB_<N>_COMPLETE" >> results/test_utilization.txt` will enable me to more easily associate metrics from `top` with each "job". However, when I do this: `cat results/test_utilization.txt | grep JOB` all I get is this:

```
$ cat results/test_utilization.txt | grep JOB
JOB_2_COMPLETE
```

It seems `test_utilization.txt` is being overwritten, or something. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>` to append

Comment: Simple enough -- thanks!

Comment: I marked it as a dupe, but it deserves a bit more info: when redirecting with `>`, every background write will continue where the previous write to the same fd left off. Any text appended in the mean time will be bulldozed over. With `>>`, every new write will append to the current end of the file, after any other data that other processes have appended.